# How to place an image on the screen from an event?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, events

I want to add an image on the screen when an event occurs. In my case, this would be from a button being clicked. I attempted to solve this myself, but the image isn't appearing.  I don't know what is wrong.

My code:

```
JButton button2 = new JButton("+");
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Execute when button is pressed
        System.out.println("button #2 working");
        label2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("50.png")));      
        label2.setLocation(10, 60);
        label2.setSize(300, 532);
        add(label2);
        //? Not working 
    }
}); 

button2.setSize(50, 40); 
button2.setFont(new Font("Arial", 1, 20));
button2.setLocation(110, 592);
button2.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
content.add(button2);
```

Comment: try to add `revalidate();` where you have your comment `//? Not working`

Comment: revalidate() only deals with updating the layout, repaint() on the other hand deals with repainting or refreshing the view (component). To give a quick analogy for this would be a simple JTextField. Whenever you type something in a text field, Swing automatically invokes repaint() for you so that it refreshes or repaints the component in order to see the change (i.e. the character typed)

Comment: I figured out a simple solution. I put an image on the screen, and set it to not be visible. image1.setVisible(false); When the button is clicked, the image will appear with image1.setVisible(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually have done something similar to what you are trying to achieve. However, I achieved this by using a different method instead. You could for example create a class MyPanel which extends JPanel and override the paintComponent() method. In the paintComponent() method you can call g.drawImage(yourImage, 0, 0,null); to add the image to your panel. Then it is a matter of creating an instance of MyPanel and adding it wherever you want on the GUI. Also, do not forget to call repaint() after you have clicked the button or you will not see the change.